# C# mailitem.saveas

Tags: c#, email

I got a problem.
I create an Outlook message with *.png in the body. Mail is correctly created and sent with all stuff in the body.
But I need to save that mail on local disc. Message is saved...but without *.png in body...
Anybody know why ?

```
string sur = label4.Text;
DateTime ddd = DateTime.Now;
String ddd2 = ddd.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string miesiac = ddd.ToString("MM");
string rok = ddd.ToString("yyyy");
string dzien = ddd.ToString("dd");
string czas = ddd.ToString("HHmmss");
string folder = ddd.ToString("yyyy-MM");

Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mailitem = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailitem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "some@example.com";
mailitem.To = txtAdres.Text;
mailitem.Subject = txtIM.Text;
mailitem.Attachments.Add(sur);
mailitem.HTMLBody = "<html><div style='font-size:12px; font-family:Tahoma;'><body> <p><img src = 'I:\\szablony\\images\\top.png'</img> <p>" + grzecznosciowa + "</p> <p>" + punkt_1 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_2 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_3 + "</p> <p> " + punkt_4 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_5 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_6 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_7 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_8 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_9 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_10 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_11 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_12 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_13 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_14 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_15 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_16 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_17 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_18 + "</p> <p>" + wkrotce + "</p> <p>" + powazanie + "</p> <p>" + dol + "</p> </body></html>";
mailitem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
string adres_msg = @"\\some\adres\examles\" + folder + @"\" + ddd2 + @"\" + txtIM.Text + "-" + ddd2 + "-" + czas + "-" + txtAPPID.Text + ".msg";
mailitem.SaveAs(adres_msg) ;
((Outlook._MailItem)mailitem).Display();
((Outlook._MailItem)mailitem).Send();
```

Comment: Most likely the path `I:\szablony\images\top.png` is not accessible from where you are saving the message.

Comment: I check this and when i put for example html file on this directiory it's work... hmmm when i drop msg manually from outlook to this folder it's work and i can see images... why....

Comment: When a save this mail is same directory where *.png are, it still not working;/ I don't have any idea why....

Comment: In that case your local Outlook has access to this path and automatically downloads referenced images. If embedding the img is vital you could consider setting the img src to data base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
mailitem.Attachments.Add(pani_c);
mailitem.Attachments.Add(pani_wc);
mailitem.Attachments.Add(powazanie2);
mailitem.Attachments.Add(dol2);

mailitem.HTMLBody = String.Format("<html><div style='font-size:12px; font-family:Tahoma;'><body> <p><img src ='cid:top.png'</img> <p><img src ='cid:pani.png'</img></p> <p>" + punkt_1 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_2 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_3 + "</p> <p> " + punkt_4 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_5 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_6 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_7 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_8 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_9 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_10 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_11 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_12 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_13 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_14 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_15 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_16 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_17 + "</p> <p>" + punkt_18 + "</p> <p><img src ='cid:tekst_pani.png'</img></p> <p><img src ='cid:powazanie.png'</img></p> <p><img src ='cid:dol.png'</img></p> </body></html>", graf, pani_c, pani_wc, powazanie2, dol2);
```